# Play 2.1.1 building dependencies

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven, playframework-2.0, sbt

I'm new to *Play framework* and working on a Java webapp using it. I understand to build *play 2.1.1* applications, we need to use *SBT*.

Questions:

1. Is this the default build system for Play? Don't we have any Play framework commands which will build, test, resolve dependencies etc?
2. Can I use Play framework with Maven / Maven repository, or if i need to use SBT only, can I use SBT with Maven repository? Is this a good practice?
3. I tried installing SBT. Extracted the downloaded zip file and added the `<SBT_HOME>\bin` directory to Windows path variable. When I execute `sbt` command, I'm getting the following error:

   `The system cannot find the file C:\installations\sbt\bin\sbtconfig.txt. java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.sbt\boot\update.log (The system cannot find the path specified)`

Am I doing anything wrong in the installation?

Comment: Even though Play's build system uses `sbt`, I never had to download it to make my apps run, you can simply use `play run`, `play compile` etc. I haven't tried [this](http://www.playframework.com/modules/maven-1.0/home) but it says you can manage your dependencies with Maven. As for your last error, I had something similar this morning and it was because I had placed `Play` in a directory I didn't have read/write access to so perhaps you can check that out..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Is this the default build system for Play?

   Yes, sbt is the default build system for Play application.
2. Can I use Play framework with Maven / Maven repository?

   Yes, by default, Play uses `Maven2 repository` and `Typesafe repository`.  Here's the default resolver:

   ```
   resolvers ++= Seq(
       "Maven Repository" at "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/",
       "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
   )
   ```

   If you need to find add a dependency, you can simply go to the Maven2 repository.

   For example, this is the repository for Google Guice

   http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.guice/guice/1.0

   You should be able to see a sbt tab, and find the code you need to write in Build.scala

   `libraryDependencies += "com.google.code.guice" % "guice" % "1.0"`
3. There's no need to install sbt if you have installed play.

   Simply `cd` to your project directory and run `play`.